# Oracle SQL Plus expdp in bat file

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012, database, sql

I try to export all my bases with a `.bat` file, but when the `.bat` file open and connect in `sqlplus`, the program don't read the last of file.

I need export and log all export with `Spool`.

The `.bat` is something like this:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
spool c:\logs\oracle\backup.log
expdp SYSTEM/usuario schemas=schemaname1 file=filename1.dmp log=logname1.log
expdp SYSTEM/usuario schemas=schemaname2 file=filename2.dmp log=logname2.log
...
expdp SYSTEM/usuario schemas=schemaname16 file=filename16.dmp log=logname16.log
spool off
```

but the program stop after `sqlplus / as sysdba` without any errors =(

Comment: @fixer1234 ok, I'll hold off on that then. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're connecting to SQL*Plus. [expdp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL803) is an OS utility and is meant to be run from outside SQL*Plus. Skip the first 2 lines.

```
expdp SYSTEM/usuario schemas=schemaname1 file=filename1.dmp log=logname1.log
expdp SYSTEM/usuario schemas=schemaname2 file=filename2.dmp log=logname2.log
...
expdp SYSTEM/usuario schemas=schemaname16 file=filename16.dmp log=logname16.log
```

Comment: I want to create a task in windows server to execute the .bat file and I run the script in windows "cmd"